# Definition of the Support of a continuous random variable in Hogg-McKean-Craig

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am reading the textbook of **Hogg-McKean-Craig "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics" (8th ed.)** and I came across the definition of the support of a continuous random variable in **Chapter 1 page 50**.

Quoting from the textbook:

" The support of a continuous random variable $X$ consists of all points $x$ such that $f_X(x) > 0$. "

(where $f_X(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$) .

The authors then proceed to give various examples of continuous random variables , such as **Example 1.7.2** **in page 51**, in which:

$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & ,  \textrm{elsewhere} \\
\frac{1}{4} \cdot e^{-\frac{x}{4}} & \text{if } 0<x< \infty
\end{cases}$.

By following the definition of Support that the authors give, it follows that the support of $X$ is $S_X=(0,\infty)$.

However I recall taking another class in probability theory , in which we had stated that **the support of a probability distribution is a closed set**.

How can we reconcile these two?

To my understanding the contradiction would be resolved if :

$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & ,  \textrm{elsewhere} \\
\frac{1}{4} \cdot e^{-\frac{x}{4}} & \text{if } 0 \leq x< \infty
\end{cases}$.

however this is not the case in the textbook.

Comment: Densities are only defined a.e., so the definition of support does not make sense in general. When $X$ has  continuous density this makes sense but it is **not** equivalent to the other (standard) definition of support you are talking about.

Comment: @geetha290krm Isn't it still "wrong" to claim that $S_X=(0,\infty)$ in the example?

Comment: According the author's non-standard definition of support we do have $S_X=(0,\infty)$.